# Mosquitto should not store and send offline messages

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying not to get the offline messages my scenario is if client1 is offline and client2 is sending messages so client1 should not receive any old messages when he reconnects and he should receive messages sent after reconnection. I am using mqtt library(npm) on client side and mosquitto server. I have tried `{clean:true}` and publish and subscribe using `{qos:0}` and  its not working.This is my code

**client2:**

```
 this.client = mqtt.connect(url, {
  clean: true
}
this.client.publish("mqtt/location", JSON.stringify(data1) ,{qos: 0});
```

**Client1:**

```
this.client = mqtt.connect(url, {
      clean: true
}
this.client.subscribe("mqtt/location", {qos: 0});
this.client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
console.log(payload);
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting clean session to true, then the only other explanation is that the messages you are receiving were published with the retained bit set. There is nothing you can do to stop your client receiving those messages, but you can detect them. Any published message that you receive from the broker that has the retained bit set is "old".

Comment: Thanks for you answer I will try this.

Comment: I tested it every time I receive a message retain is false.

Comment: You need to clear any old retained messages. The easiest way to do this is to stop mosquitto and delete it's persistence file